# Value of type '' has no member '' in swift

Tags: ios, swift

The following code gives error `value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'retrieveContactsWitStore'` in `self.retrieveContactsWithStore(store: store)` line, irrespective of using `self`keyword. I have referred to many similar questions, but I didn't get any working solution and explanation.  Can anyone explain why it is giving this error and how to overcome this ?

```
@IBAction func btnContactsTapped() {
        let store = CNContactStore()

        if CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts) == .notDetermined {
            store.requestAccess(for: .contacts, completionHandler: { (authorized: Bool, error: Error?) -> Void in
                if authorized {
                    retrieveContactsWithStore(store: store)
                }
            })
        } else if CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts) == .authorized {
            self.retrieveContactsWithStore(store: store)
        }


        func retrieveContactsWithStore(store: CNContactStore) {
            do {
                let groups = try store.groups(matching: nil)
                let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsInGroup(withIdentifier: groups[0].identifier)
                //let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsMatchingName("John")
                let keysToFetch = [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName), CNContactEmailAddressesKey] as [Any]

                let contacts = try store.unifiedContacts(matching: predicate, keysToFetch: keysToFetch as! [CNKeyDescriptor])
//                self.objects = contacts
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                    print("Contacts: \(contacts)")
                })
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your function `retrieveContactsWithStore` is *inside* the `btnContactsTapped` function. Move it out

Comment: Your indentation looks bad. Could be part of the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `retrieveContactsWithStore` must be **outside** of the `@IBAction`

```
@IBAction func btnContactsTapped() 
{
    let store = CNContactStore()

    if CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts) == .notDetermined {
        store.requestAccess(for: .contacts, completionHandler: { (authorized, error) in
            if authorized {
                self.retrieveContactsWithStore(store: store)
            }
        })
    } else if CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts) == .authorized {
        self.retrieveContactsWithStore(store: store)
    }
}


func retrieveContactsWithStore(store: CNContactStore) 
{
    do {
        let groups = try store.groups(matching: nil)
        let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsInGroup(withIdentifier: groups[0].identifier)
        //let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsMatchingName("John")
        let keysToFetch = [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName), CNContactEmailAddressesKey] as [Any]

        let contacts = try store.unifiedContacts(matching: predicate, keysToFetch: keysToFetch as! [CNKeyDescriptor])
//      self.objects = contacts
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("Contacts: \(contacts)")
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: @meaning-matters, could you please elaborate about the problem in the indentation ?

Comment: @Sravan He already fixed your indentation it in the Aug 14 edit.